# How to add tiger schema to the database search path?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tiger

> The tiger schema must be added to the database search path for the functions to work properly.

I just started recently to use tiger dataset and postgres database and I have basic understanding of both. I would like to fix the following:

```
loader_generate_census_script: command not found
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include more information about the steps you've taken to arrive at that error.

Comment: @Chris  not sure how to clarify this any better!  are you familiar with how to install postgis & tiger dataset, postgis_tiger geocoder?

Comment: No, I'm not, which is part of what you could add to clarify - the steps you took to install them, or at least a link to the instructions you followed. The current answer states it should have been done automatically with proper installation. Knowing the steps you took may point out the issue/solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm well if you installed with

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

It should do that automatically for you unless your user has an overriding search_path.

Anyrate standard way is to do:

ALTER DATABASE gisdb SET search_path="$user",public, tiger;

Note the settings don't take affect until you reconnect to the database.